# How to post a file to a remote URL using got?

Tags: node.js, node.js-got

I'm trying to post a file to a remote URL using got. But it is not working as expected.

I have tried the following

```
const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "image/png"
}

const requestProperties = {
    method: 'POST',
    url,
    headers,
    json: fs.createReadStream(file.path)
}

const response = await got(requestProperties);
```

Comment: What is not working? What error are you getting?

Comment: What format does the API expect? `multipart/form-data` or a direct binary? Have a look at the documentation for the [body option](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/main/documentation/2-options.md#body)

Comment: @chill389cc The error is like an unsupported media type. I think I am using JSON option instead of the body.

Comment: @Phil API expects "image/png".

Comment: Thank you @Phil. Issue resolved by using body instead of json.

Comment: It pays to read the documention

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [@phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil)
I have used body property instead of json.

```
const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "image/png"
}

const requestProperties = {
    method: 'POST',
    url,
    headers,
    body: fs.createReadStream(file.path)
}

const response = await got(requestProperties);
```

Comment: Relevant portion of the `got()` doc [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/fd7536078148461ad9cc72f2d57f89c98ca8f63e/documentation/2-options.md#body).